# Updated the PHP on server. Getting this error: Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly

Tags: error-message, server, permissions

I am running Amazon Ec2 instance and tried updating the PHP on the site using this guide: http://brianshim.com/webtricks/update-amazon-ami-php5-3-to-php5-4/

And now this is the error I am receiving:
Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in /var/www/html/staging/public/index.php

I tried resetting the permissions, and restored the old http config files, to no avail. I have no idea what it could be. I checked php.ini for open_basedir and did not find it.

Could it be the permissions?

Answer (score 1):

All Craft is doing is using PHP's [is_file()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.is-file.php) method to check if the supplied path to `craft/app/index.php` returns true or not.

Take Craft out of the picture and setup a simple PHP script that does

```
<?php

if (is_file('path/to/craft/app/index.php')) {
    echo "found it";
} else {
    echo "oops";
}
```

If you get an "oops", then there is some environmental issue (PHP permissions, open_basedir restrictions, Suhosin, mod_security, etc.) that is preventing PHP from finding that file that will need to be addressed.

If it is permissions related (the most common cause), there is a handy script here that will properly set the permissions for a Craft install: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts/tree/master/scripts

Comment: Thanks @brad-bell! That's great idea. Quick question: where should I set up this script?

Comment: Putin in your public HTML folder, name it "test.php", then load up `yoursite.com/test.php` in a browser.

Comment: Great, thanks for the prompt reply. I will try that now :)

Comment: Unfortunately, even if I navigate to /test.php after I placed it in the public folder, it still spits out "Could not find your craft/ folder. Please ensure that $craftPath is set correctly in /var/www/html/production/public/index.php"

I tried a var_dump of the $path as a sanity check and it did spit out the right path to the index of the app. I'm guessing it's likely a permission issue right?

Comment: Oh wait, i put it in the wrong directory. I'm getting "found it" it now

Comment: I got the "found it" from the test.php actually haha. No idea why it's saying other for the index.php though.

Comment: Did you use the full path to `app/index.php` or a relative one like in `$craftPath`?  Try setting `$craftPath` to an absolute path?

Comment: Yeah I used the absolute path "../craft/app/index.php" inside my test.php file and it spit out oops. It's obviously there so it seems like it doesn't have permission to access.

Comment: Guessing I should run this script: https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts/blob/master/scripts/set_perms.sh ?

Comment: That's the one.